# How to use contracts from project dependencies in Brownie scripts?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin-contracts, import, brownie

I want to deploy a contract directly accessible in `OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.2.0` Brownie package without changes, namely [ERC1967Proxy](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/proxy/ERC1967/ERC1967Proxy.sol)
and other non-abstract contracts from Brownie console.

How can I import it in a Brownie script or console?

My `brownie-config.yaml`:

```yaml
compiler:
  solc:
    version: 0.8.2
    remappings:
      - "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable=~/.brownie/packages/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable@4.2.0/contracts"
      - "@openzeppelin-upgradeable=/home/etsvigun/.brownie/packages/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable@4.2.0"
      - "@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.2.0"
dependencies:
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.2.0
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable@4.2.0
```

Imports work fine in Solidity code, from both remappings, like

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/UUPSUpgradeable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";
```

Trying to import contracts from packages just by names results in errors:

```py
>>> from brownie import Proxy
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'Proxy' from 'brownie' (~/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.9/site-packages/brownie/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this pattern in a [yearn repo](https://github.com/yearn/brownie-strategy-mix/blob/master/scripts/deploy.py), maybe this is what you are looking for ?

```
from brownie import project

Vault = project.load(
    Path.home() / ".brownie" / "packages" / config["dependencies"][0]
).Vault
```

Answer (score 4):

You're close.

The `dependencies` section identifies where you want to download. You've correctly placed that part using github syntax. You want to download organization `OpenZeppelin` with repo `openzeppelin-contracts`.

Then, what you want to do is, "remap" your imports so that a keyword you've defined lines up with that package.

You're "remapping" `"@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable` to `/home/etsvigun/.brownie/packages/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable@4.2.0/contracts`. Instead, try this:

```yaml
compiler:
  solc:
    version: 0.8.2
    remappings:
      - "@openzeppelin-upgradeable=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable@4.2.0"
      - "@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.2.0"
dependencies:
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.2.0
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable@4.2.0
```

Don't use the entire file path when remapping.

Comment: The point of the question is "how do I import in a script"
I.e. there's `Escrow`, which is not abstract and therefore can be instantiated.
```
 brownie console
...
Brownie environment is ready.
>>> Escrow
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Escrow' is not defined
```
Remapping above is just sidestepping the fact that Brownie quirk when you remap 2 packages with common prefix.

Comment: I.e. these remappings work OK in contracts. I want to understand how to import contracts from packages in scripts. Will update the question.